# SwiftUI Localization System without use of Localizable.strings?

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, localization

I am using XCodes localization strategy for the first time. And I find it to be a little uncomfortable to use...
With hundred of localizable strings throughout an app, I wonder if there is not a better way to do it.

What's not so likeable is missing type-safety, including possible global renaming of string properties, compile-time consistency-checks (everything translated?), maintainability. The list goes on.

**Proposal**

I wrote a draft of a different approach. (This is intended purely for a SwiftUI environment, not thought about any Storyboard localisation)
**I wonder if there's something about this solution further down the road, which might forbid to use this.** Would this be accepted in App Review? (Why not?) 
After doing quite some research I wonder why everybody seems to go only as far as replacing by string names by enums, and maybe the use of some external tooling.

**This would be the top level object to access (name spacing needed later):**

```
enum Localizables {
    case headlineForSomething
    case bodytext
    case somethingElse
    case buttonTitle
}
```

**The actual translation results live in these extensions.**

Each extensio lives in a separate file.swift. The equivalent of Localizable.strings / Language X:

```
extension Localizables {
        private var en: String {
        switch self {
        case .headlineForSomething:
            return "Headline for something in English"
        case .bodytext:
            return "Bodytext in English"
        case .somethingElse:
            return "Something else in English"
        case .buttonTitle:
            return "Button title in English"
        }
    }
}


extension Localizables {
    private var de: String {
        switch self {
        case .headlineForSomething:
            return "Headline for something in German"
        case .bodytext:
            return "Bodytext in German"
        case .somethingElse:
            return "Something else in German"
        case .buttonTitle:
            return "Button title in German"
        }
    }
}
```

**The simple core of the system**
1. Included languages have to be listed initially.
2. This property is exposed with the resulting string.

```
extension Localizables {
    // 1: 
    private var availableLocales: [Language] {
               [
                   Language(ressources: self.en, name: "en"),
                   Language(ressources: self.de, name: "de")
               ]
           }
            // 2:
           var localized: String {
               return self.translate()
           }

           private func translate() -> String {
               for lang in self.availableLocales {
                   if Locale.current.languageCode == lang.name {
                       return lang.ressources
                   }
                   else { return "not tranlated" }
               }
                return "not tranlated xxx"
           }
}

struct Language {
    let ressources: String
    let name: String
}
```

**The usage of my little approach is as simple as that:**

```
let someStringToBeLocalized: String = Localizables.headlineForSomething.localized
```

**Current ToDos and disadvantages I see:**
The cases certainly have to be name-spaced for better accessibility
The cases could(?) include variables to insert computed properties like numbers into ie. sentences.
I'm not sure if translation service providers would work with anything else than Localizable.string files. Again: why not?

Comment: There are preexisting libraries for better and specifically type-safe localisations, such as [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift).

Comment: Do you know think this approach is very expensive with iterations over all the enum cases instead of using mapping keys on the localizable.Strings?

Comment: @good4pc Thanks! You mean it would be computationally expensive? This would certainly be a killer argument.

Comment: @HelloTimo Consider having 1000's of enum cases like that and frequently called couple of times. Check how much time it takes to compute everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep custom implementation and also support `.environment` that SwiftUI provides by using the trick of getting the `locale` from the view. As [EnvironmentValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) are propagated through a view hierarchy it requires special treatment.

To turn this over your advantage you can provide

```swift
struct LocalizedText: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    let key: String
    let localizedString: (_ languageCode: String?, _ key: String) -> (String)

    var body: Text {
        let languageCode = locale.languageCode ?? Locale.current.languageCode
        let localizedString = localizedString(languageCode, key)

        return Text(localizedString)
    }
}
```

having that:

```swift
extension Localizables {
    static func localizedString(_ key: String, languageCode: String) -> String {
        ... // do what is required in your case
    }

    static func localizedText(_ key: String) -> some View {
        LocalizedText(key: key, localizedString: { languageCode, key in
            localizedString(key, languageCode: languageCode)
        })
    }
}
```

[I made a blog post about this.](https://nonameplum.github.io/posts/SwiftUI%20custom%20localization%20strings%20handling/)